# Cannot use fit method in seaborn.distplot

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe with many columns, one of which counts the duration of a process in months. Sample data is available bellow:

```
ID      Unit      Duration
231      TS          2
427      SP          4
291      EI          1
312      SP          3
```

So, I am trying to plot the histogram, filtered by units and fitting it (mostly for visualization purposes) to `stats.expon`, which is the best fit for most units. Seems simple enough:

```
graph = sns.distplot(df[df['Unit'] == 'SP']['Duration'], kde = False, fit = stats.expon)
```

But it raises `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc add`. What am I doing wrong? I'm kind of new do matplotlib and seaborn, so excuse me if this is trivial.